# is it safe to drive 8 ws2812b's from an arduino's 5v pin

Tags: arduino, led-strip

I am doing some light testing with a small 8 pixel ws2812b strip. I'm wondering if there is any risk of damaging the arduino (nano) by driving the 8 pixels directly off the `5v` pin (rather than an external power source). I'm using this pin to simplify the test environment. Eventually more pixels would be driven by a USB battery bank (which would also power the arduino).

Using my DMM, I'm only seeing about 90 mA draw for the 8 pixels. I think that should be fine, but I'm still new to this device and don't want to do something dumb that would burn it out needlessly.

Everything else is as per [the recommended layout](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/030/892/medium800/leds_Wiring-Diagram.png?1456961114)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you make sure the max draw of full RGB white is not drawn for all 8 at any given time, you should be within the Limits of the on board 5V regulator. Since this draw depends on your code, you can easily make sure that all 8 leds are not on 100% full draw at the same time. At 65 ~ 70 mA full draw, (20mA red, 20mA blue, 20mA green, and <10mA for the WS2812 itself) times 8, a 525 to 560 mA load at full white, you could have 7 fully on at any given moment without major malfunction. The ATMega on the Arduino itself should take under 50 mA worst case.